# React children component not re-rendering after parent state changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to create a simple card game. When a card is clicked, it should be selected and assigned a classname of " selectedCard". So when it re-renders, the selected card will be lifted up. However, the selected card did not lift up onClick, my guess is that it did not re-render.

Here is my code snippet:

Player.js:

```
const Player = (props) =>{
    const [selectedCards, setSelectCard] = useState([]);

    const selectCard = (card) => {
        let newSelectedCards = selectedCards
        if(newSelectedCards.includes(card) ) {
            newSelectedCards.splice(newSelectedCards.indexOf(card), 1)
        } else {
            newSelectedCards.push(card)
        }
        setSelectCard(newSelectedCards)
        console.log('changed');
    }


    return(
            <div className="player-container">
                {props.cards && props.cards.map((card, i) => {
                    let selected = selectedCards.includes(card)
                    return(<Card key={i} card={card} user="player" selectCard={selectCard} selected={selected}/>)
                }
          )}
    )
}
```

Card.js

```
const Card = (props) =>{
    const path = props.card.imagePath
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(props.selected)

    useEffect(() => { setSelected(props.selected) }, [props.selected]);
    {/*My effort to make it work*/}

    const classname = (selected) ? "selectedcard" : ""
            return(
                <img onClick={() => props.selectCard(props.card)}  className={"card " + classname} alt = "card-image" src={images[path]}/>)
}
```

css

```
.selectedcard{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the state while updating it, if you do so React sees in reference check that thee reference is same and assumes nothing has changed and doesn't trigger a re-render.

Follow the concept of immutability while updating react state. You can update it using `Array.prototype.slice` and `spread syntax` for deleting the item and using `Array.prototype.concat` for adding an item

```
const selectCard = (card) => {
    let newSelectedCards =[];
    if(newSelectedCards.includes(card) ) {
        const index = selectedCards.indexOf(card)
        newSelectedCards = [...selectedCards.slice(0, index), ...selectedCards.slice(index + 1)]
    } else {
        newSelectedCards = selectedCards.concat([card]);
    }
    setSelectCard(newSelectedCards)
    console.log('changed');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem! I